# PHP cURL throwing 500 error in post through API

Tags: php, curl, post

I am sending data using `POST` request from wordpress to vreasy through `API`. But it is giving me below error.

```
{"message":"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vreasy_prod_2`.`reservations`, CONSTRAINT `fk_reservations_listor` FOREIGN KEY (`listor_id`) REFERENCES `listors` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION), query was: INSERT INTO `reservations` (`id`, `adults`, `kids`, `additional_description`, `owner_additional_description`, `accommodation_cost`, `currency_id`, `listing_id`, `host_id`, `guest_id`, `status`, `checkin`, `checkout`, `created_at`, `listor_id`, `gateway_listor_id`, `portal_uid`, `subscription_id`, `user_id`, `language_id`, `updated_at`, `auto_email_enabled`, `auto_sms_enabled`, `auto_task_enabled`, `auto_email_run_at`, `auto_sms_run_at`, `auto_task_run_at`, `original_parent_id`, `checkin_gmt`, `checkout_gmt`, `custom_eta`, `custom_etd`, `net_amount_for_pm`, `portal_service_fee_for_pm`, `channel_service_fee`, `gross_amount_paid_by_guest`, `extra_data`, `payment_fee`, `booking_conditions`, `confirmed_at`, `custom_eta_method`, `custom_etd_method`, `is_payments_automatable`, `is_pending_statement`, `statement_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)","exception":{},"request_params":{"controller":"reservations","action":"post","module":"api","body":{"checkin":"2018-09-25 15:00:00","checkout":"2018-09-27 11:00:00","listor_id":0,"gateway_listor_id":0,"user_id":1,"adults":1,"status":"UNCONFIRMED","guest":{"fname":"Chirag","lname":"Modi","email":"cmodi@atlas.com","phone":"123456798"},"listing_id":177035},"request-id":"W5u82-wkexMY6IkfseMiXAAAAIY","user_id":1,"agent":"user"},"code":500}
```

and here is my PHP code which i am using.

```
$url = 'https://api.vreasy.com/reservations';
$api_key = "api-key";
$fields = array(
    'checkin' => '2018-09-25 15:00:00',
    'checkout' => '2018-09-27 11:00:00',
    'listor_id' => 0,
    'gateway_listor_id' => 0,
    'user_id' => 1,
    'adults' => 1,
    'property_id' => 177035,
    'status' => 'UNCONFIRMED',
    'guest' => array(
        'fname' => 'Chirag',
        'lname' => 'Modi',
        'email' => 'cmodi@atlas.com',
        'phone' => '123456798'
    )
);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key . ":"); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

I have searched this topic, and mostly showing same method to send `POST` request. 
here is the documentation URL for reference https://api.vreasy.com/docs/public-api/#operation/post_reservation

Comment: I'd suggest contacting them. It's probably an error on their end, and not something you can fix.

Comment: ya, i thought so, i have already raised a support to them.